# AngularJS submenu with ng-show

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-show

I have made a directive that has menu-items in it, some of the menuitems have submenu items in them. Directive is made so that when you click on the menu-item it opens its submenu. My problem is that when I click on one menu-item it opens its submenu and when I click the other menu-item it opens it aswell so I have two submenus open.
I want it to close all other submenus when I click menu-item and open only clicked menu-items submenu. How should I do it?

My html code:

```
<menu visible="leftVisible" alignment="left">
<menu-item hash="first" show="menu1">

    Side Menu item
    <ul ng-show="menu1">
        <li>
            <a>First submenu item</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>First submenu item</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</menu-item>
<menu-item hash="second" show="menu2">

    Side Menu item
    <ul ng-show="menu2">
        <li>
            <a >Second submenu item</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a >Second submenu item</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</menu-item>
<menu-item hash="third">Side Menu item</menu-item>
```

And this is my directive code:

```
menuItem.directive("menuItem", function() {
     return {
     restrict: "E",
     template: "<div ng-click='toggle($event)' ng-transclude></div>",
     transclude: true,
     scope: {
           hash: "@",
           show: '=',
     },
     link: function($scope) {
         $scope.toggle = function(e) {
               $scope.show = !$scope.show;
         }

     }
 }
});
```

So what should I do to close other submenus when clicking on menu-item?

Comment: how it looks your menu directive? a plunker would be great to be able to suggest you a valid idea.

Comment: @elvin Made a plunker -> https://plnkr.co/edit/lBWXqDMwFdNlHV59eM8e?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're wrapping those menuItem inside your menu directive, you can let it know which item was clicked last passing its name to a property in the parent scope like this:

```
app.directive('menu', function() {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<div ng-class='{ show: visible, left: alignment === \"left\", right: alignment === \"right\" }' ng-transclude></div>",
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        visible: "=",
        alignment: "@"
    }
};
});

app.directive("menuItem", function() {
 return {
     restrict: "E",
     template: "<div ng-click='toggle()' ng-transclude></div>",
     transclude: true,
     scope: {
         hash: "@"
     },
     link: function($scope, elm) {
         $scope.toggle = function(e) {
            $scope.$parent.activeItem = $scope.hash;
        }
     }
 }
});
```

then you can use that value with ng-show to hide the others:

```
<menu visible="leftVisible" alignment="left">
<menu-item hash="first">

  Side Menu item
  <ul ng-show="activeItem === 'first'">
    <li>
      <a>First submenu item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>First submenu item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</menu-item>
<menu-item hash="second">

  Side Menu item (If I click this I would like all the other submenus to close, this case should cover all the Side Menu items)
  <ul ng-show="activeItem === 'second'">
    <li>
      <a>Second submenu item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Second submenu item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</menu-item>
<menu-item hash="third">Side Menu item</menu-item>
```

I've updated your [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IDhxkICbw5TmzxUqxXd6?p=preview) with these changes. Hope this helps.